Climbing through the mountains on all paths
Narrative
We are standing at the foot of a mountain. To find the best route when climbing the mountain, let's consider all possible routes.
On our route, there is no point lower than our starting point. To describe the route, we use the four directions:
N (north, or 'up'), S (south, or 'down'), W (west, or 'left'), and E (east, or 'right'). 

In order not to overtax our strength, we set the number of steps to \$n\$, where \$n \ge 1\$,
and accept any point that is strictly higher than our starting point and vertically above it as a possible end point of the tour.
Examples
There is always the 'direttissima', [NN...N], the most challenging route to the highest possible peak.
But there are also easy walks, for example, if \$n\$ is odd the walk [WW.. (floor(n/2)-times), EE.. (floor(n/2)-times), N] is a route that meets our requirements.
Task
List all routes of given length \$n\$ that meet our requirements as strings over the alphabet {N,S,W,E} describing the steps of the walk.
To do so, write a function that takes a positive integer as input and returns a list of N-S-W-E-strings.
The order of the tours is irrelevant. The strings can be output as a comma separated list, or line by line. This is code-golf, so each language's shortest code in bytes wins.
Test
For n = 4, the following list should be generated (regardless the order):
NNWE, NSNN, NENW, NEWN, NWNE, NNNN, NNNS, NNSN, 
NNEW, WNNE, WNEN, WENN, NWEN, ENNW, ENWN, EWNN.

Remark
The setup is similar to that in question Walks in Nice (Nizza), but the solution set (meaning the set of paths) is structurally quite different. This difference is most evident in the fact that the number of paths in the case here is always a perfect square. As a result, a fundamentally different approach may be possible.
The question belongs to the field of enumerative combinatorics. If you want to know more about it, you can find it on Wikipedia: Block walking, Lattice path. Related OEIS sequences: A378061 and A378060.

I think I can infer this from the test cases, but just to clarify, are steps North always going to increase elevation while steps South decrease it and steps East or West have no effect on elevation? The phrasing of "strictly higher than our starting point and vertically above it" is making me think I'm missing something--or, oh, does that mean the destination just has to be directly north of the start? Sorry... I could have figured that much out from the existing answers, but still, uh, I guess I'm just having a bad day and I don't know why I'm even still posting this comment ;_;

@Unrelated String Yes to all your questions.

Python 3, 106 bytes
f=lambda n,N=0,E=0,*p:sum([f(n-1,i%2*i+N,~i%2*~-i+E,*p,'WNES'[i])for i in[-1,0,1,2]if~N*n],(1>E==n<N)*[p])

Try it online!

105

Ruby, 101 bytes
->n{((a=?E*-~n)..?E+a).map{|x|x[0,n]if/^((N\g<1>S?|E*W*)+)(?<=S)$/=~x&&x.count(?W)==x.count(?E)}-[p]}

This is very slow, but it manages to finish for n=4 eventually on my machine. Try it for n=3 (it times out for n=4, lol)
Whoever said regex can't find matching parentheses? :D
Explanation:

((a=?E*-~n)..?E+a) generates the list of strings ['EEEEE', 'EEEEF', 'EEEEG', ..., 'EEEEEC', 'EEEEED', 'EEEEEE'] (for n=4). This is obviously extreme overkill but does contain all of the 5-length strings with alphabet NSEW, and then some. (Why 5? You'll see later.)

We map over that list and test for two conditions.

The first is the regex /^((N\g<1>S?|E*W*)+)(?<=S)$/. This is a recursive regex that tests the N/S part. It does this by matching 1 or more of the following: N followed by a recursive call to itself (\g<1>, technically a recursive call to the first capture group because we want to omit the ^ and $) followed by an optional S, or any number of E and W.
We also tack on a positive lookbehind (?<=S) at the end to make sure the string ends with S. Instead of generating 4-length strings that end at 1 or higher, we generate 5-length strings that end at 0 or higher and then chop off the S at the end.

The second is just x.count(?W)==x.count(?E). It feels like this should be shorter but I can't find anything.


Note that the original list contained a few unwanted 6-length strings, but all of them have at least one non-NSEW character except for EEEEEE, which doesn't pass either condition.

If both conditions hold, evaluate to x[0,n] (take the first n characters, i.e. remove the extraneous S). Otherwise, implicitly evaluate to nil.

Remove the nil elements by performing -[p]. p is a function that prints and returns its argument. In this case the argument is nil, so it prints nothing and returns nil.


A bonus solution, which I think is super slick but is sadly much longer:
->n{(i=4**n).upto(2*i){puts$&.chop.tr'0-3','NSEW'if/^((0\g<1>1?|2*3*)+)$/=~_1.digits(4)*''&&$&.count(?2)==$&.count(?3)}}


Charcoal, 46 bytes
Ｎθ⊞υωＦυ«≔⁼№ιN№ιSη¿‹ＬιθＦ✂SNWEη⊞υ⁺ικ¿›⁼№ιW№ιEη⟦ι

Try it online! Link to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on my answer to Walks in Nice (Nizza) but instead of printing walks whose vertical distance is zero prints walks whose vertical distance is not zero but whose horizontal distance is zero.

05AB1E, 35 33 bytes
'€Ã©Iãʒ®À2ôδÃÇ`È·<ηO¤0›sd`r6b-O_P

Based on my answer for the Walks in Nice (Nizza) challenge. The difference is that the _ (==0, aka no vertical change) is replaced with 0› (>0, aka climbed), and a horizontal filter is added (6b-O_, aka not wondered east/west, but went straight up).
Try it online.
Explanation:
'€Ã                  '# Push dictionary string "news"
   ©                  # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    Iã                # Cartesian product with the input
      ʒ               # Filter this list by:
       ®À2ôδÃ         #  Split the "ew" and "sn" in loose groups:
       ®À             #   Push "news" from `®`, and rotate it once: "ewsn"
         2ô           #   Split into pairs: ["ew","sn"]
           δ          #   Using the current string and this pair as arguments:
            Ã         #    Keep only those characters
       Ç              #  Convert it to a pair of codepoint-integer lists
        `             #  Pop and push both lists separately to the stack
         È·<          #  IsEven *2 -1 (North is now 1; South is -1)
            η         #  Get the prefixes
             O        #  Sum each prefix
              ¤       #  Get the last sum (without popping the list)
               0›     #  Check whether it's positive (>0)
                      #  (aka, there are more "n" than "s" and we've climbed)
                 s    #  Swap to get the list of cumulative sums again
                  d   #  Check for each whether it's non-negative (>=0)
                      #  (aka for every "s" there should have been at least one
                      #  preceding "n")
                   `  #  Dump all those >=0 checks to the stack
        r             #  Reverse the stack
         6b           #  Push 6, and convert it to binary: 110
           -          #  Subtract (East is now -9; West is 9)
            O         #  Sum them together
             _        #  Check that this sum is 0
                      #  (aka, an equal amount of "e" and "w")
        P             #  Check if everything on the stack is truthy
                      # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)

See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section How to use the dictionary?) to understand why '€Ã is "news".

Jelly, (19?) 26 bytes
19 bytes using the integers \$[1,4]\$ as the directions WSEN, respectively.
4ṗµı*ÄḞAƑa$aĊ¬$ƲṪµƇị“WSEN”

A monadic Link that accepts an integer and yields a list of lists of characters.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
4ṗµı*ÄḞAƑa$aĊ¬$ƲṪµƇị“WSEN” - Link: integer, Steps
4ṗ                         - [1..4] Cartesian power {Steps}
                             -> all lists of [1..4] of length Steps
  µ              µƇ        - keep those Potentials for which:
   ı*                      -   -1 exponentiate {Potential} (vectorises)
     Ä                     -   cumulative sums -> "Stops" (Gaussian integers)
               Ʋ           -   last four links as a monad - f(Stops):
      Ḟ                    -     Real parts {Stops} -> "Heights"
          $                -     last two links as a monad - f(Heights):
        Ƒ                  -       is invariant under?:
       A                   -         absolute values
         a                 -       logical AND {Heights} (vectorises)
                                   -> "HeightsOrZeros" (Zeros if went below start)
              $            -     last two links as a monad - f(Stops):
            Ċ              -       imaginary parts {Stops} -> "Laterals"
             ¬             -       logical NOT (vectorises) -> isCentredForEach
           a               -     {HeightsOrZeros} logical AND {isCentredForEach} (vectorises)
                Ṫ          -   tail
                   ị“WSEN” - index into "WSEN" (vectorises)


JavaScript (V8), 89 bytes
f=(n,y=1,x=0,s='',i=2)=>y*n--?[...'ENWS'].map(c=>f(n,i--%2+y,i%2+x,s+c)):y>1&!x&&print(s)

Try it online!
From my Nice
88 by returning

f=(n,y=1,x=0,s='',i=2)=>y*n--?[...'ENWS'].flatMap(c=>f(n,i--%2+y,i%2+x,s+c)):y>1&!x?s:[]

APL+WIN, 100 bytes
Prompts for n
(0=↑¨m='s')/m←((+/¨m='s')<+/¨m='n')/m←((+/¨m='e')=+/¨m='w')/m←,⍎∊((¯1+⎕)⍴⊂'''nsew''∘.,'),⊂'''nsew'''

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 74 bytes
{E,S,W,N}[[#]]&/@Select[Range@4~Tuples~#,Tr[I^#]>0Re@Accumulate[I^#]&]&

Try it online!
Returns a list of lists containing {E,S,W,N}. For output without delimiters, prepend Print@@ (+7 bytes): Try it online!.
 is \[VectorLessEqual].
       Range@4~Tuples~#                                 paths of given length
Select[                ,                            &]  filter by:
                                0Re@Accumulate[I^#]      path stays in the right half-plane
                        Tr[I^#]>0                         path ends directly right of start
{E,S,W,N}[[#]]&/@ %                                     translate to letters

x>0 is only True if x is a noncomplex, positive value, and remains unevaluated otherwise (non-True values are falsy).

Always love when you don't need a loop and are shorter than the python answers!

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 176 bytes
f[n_]:=(s={"N","S","E","W"}~Tuples~n;StringJoin/@Pick[s,#[[-1]][[1]]==0&&#[[-1]][[2]]>0&&Min[#[[All,2]]]>=0&/@Accumulate/@(s/.{"N"->{0,1},"S"->{0,-1},"E"->{1,0},"W"->{-1,0}})])

Try it online!
Explanation
Create all possible paths with Tuples then convert them into a coordinate system. Use Pick with the three restricitons imposed (finish vertically above,finish above the starting point, do not ever go below the starting point) to select the allowed paths. Finally convert into a concatenated string.

91 bytes using complex numbers (> is only defined for both arguments real) and printing lines instead of returning.  is \[VectorLessEqual].

And a belated welcome to cgse, happy to see more mathematica users :)

Very instructive use of complex numbers and VectorLessEqual! I must remember them for future ones. You should post this as a solution!

Uiua, 45 44 bytes
▽⤚≡⌟(××>₀⊣:/×⊸≥₀\+:=₀/+∩-°⊟₄≡=¤)⊸⧅⋅⋅1:"WESN"

Pad
Edit: shaved off a byte using experimental sided subscripts.
Explanation
Take all k-permutations of the directions, then test if they are valid: they should have equal numbers of W and E; at any time have >= counts of N to S as well as > counts at the end.
▽⤚≡⌟(××>₀⊣:/×⊸≥₀\+:=₀/+∩-°⊟₄≡=¤)⊸⧅⋅⋅1:"WESN"
                                 ⧅⋅⋅1:"WESN"   # generate all k-perms
▽⤚≡⌟(                           )              # filter by
                            ≡=¤                # compare string to each direction
                       ∩-°⊟₄                   # for each char, E-W and N-S
     ××                                        # valid iff:
                   =₀/+                        # - overall E-W = 0
           /×⊸≥₀\+:                            # - at each step, N-S >= 0
       >₀⊣:                                    # - at last step, N-S > 0
    


Python, 259 96 bytes
Python port of @l4m2's JavaScript answer.
Saved 163 bytes thanks to @Unrelated String

Golfed version. Attempt This Online!
def g(z,v=1,h=0,c='',d=2):
 for x in'ENWS'*(z>(1>h==z!=print(c))):d-=1;g(z-1,v+d%2,h+~d%2,c+x,d)

Ungolfed version. Attempt This Online!
# Counter for tracking printed paths
cnt = 0

# Function to print path and increment counter
def print_path(path):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    print(path, cnt)

# Main recursive function to find valid paths
def find_paths(length, vertical_pos=1, horizontal_pos=0, current_path='', direction=2):
    global cnt
    # Base case: if we've used all steps
    if vertical_pos * length == 0:
        # Only print if we're at position (2, 0)
        if vertical_pos > 1 and horizontal_pos == 0:
            print_path(current_path)
        return

    # Try all four directions: East, North, West, South
    for dir in ['E', 'N', 'W', 'S']:
        # Calculate new positions based on direction
        new_direction = direction - 1
        direction-=1
        new_vertical_move = 1 if new_direction % 2 else 0  # 1 for N/S
        new_horizontal_move = 0 if new_direction % 2 else 1  # 1 for E/W

        # Recursive call with updated positions
        find_paths(
            length - 1,                         # Decrease remaining steps
            new_vertical_move + vertical_pos,   # New vertical position
            new_horizontal_move + horizontal_pos,  # New horizontal position
            current_path + dir,                 # Add direction to path
            new_direction                       # Update direction counter
        )

# Start the path finding with length 4
find_paths(4)


...am I missing something, or is global cnt completely extraneous, while this also relies on an external function p being defined? You don't even need to number the walks as you output them, so you should just be able to use print. ...to say nothing of the output seeming to be completely wrong anyways? A little embarrassed I golfed this down to 96 before noticing :P

(but seriously I can't tell how the n=4 output corresponds to the real one and the n=5 isn't even the same length)
